# Huawei E173 Mobile Broadband not detected in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

There are a number of posts to this effect, but none have solved my problem yet. My USB modem was detected fine in 14.04 but since upgrading to 16.04, I have not been able to connect with it except on rare occasions.

```
lancek@lance-HP-EliteBook-8760w:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

lancek@lance-HP-EliteBook-8760w:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 025: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)
....

lancek@lance-HP-EliteBook-8760w:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1446 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x140c -m 0x01 -M "55534243123456780000000000000011060000000000000000000000000000"
Look for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 025 on bus 003
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Serial No.: not provided
Looking for active driver ...
OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
OK, message successfully sent
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

Despite the optimistic response above, I can get no further.
In the network utility the Mobile Broadband network does not display.

Any assistance HUGELY appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Open folder `/usr/share/usb_modeswitch` with `sudo nautilus`, open configPack.tar.gz & then open file `12d1:1446`,  check the target product list

Comment: The file contains the following: `# Huawei, newer modems, and rebrandings
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="1001,1404,1406,140b,140c,1412,1417,141b,1429,1432,1433,1436,14ac,1506,150c,1511"
HuaweiNewMode=1`. My modem is an E173u-2. Can you advise from here? Thanks very much!